# I am new to aragodb and currently exploring on graphs basically, So is there a multiple ways to create graphs in arango, Any help is appreciated

Tags: arangodb, aql, arangojs

Multiple ways of creating graphs in arango

I had created few document collections which represents nodes and a edge collection which represents relationship between these nodes. There are multiple graphs that needs to be connected, As of now we are communicating between different collections of edges and documents/nodes via _key or_id, So Is there any better approach/way to handle this.

Just want to know, Is there any other approach of creating graphs.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.